# download log - modify and use last line

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to shorten or simplify my code.
I want to download a log file from an internal server which is updated every 10 seconds, but I'm only running my script every 10 or 15 minutes.
The log file is semicolon seperated and has many rows in it I don't use. So my workflow is as following.

1. get current date in YYYYMMDD format
2. download the file
3. delay for waiting that the file is finished downloading
4. trim the file to the rows I need
5. only process last line of the file
6. delete the files

I'm new to python and if you could help me to shorten/simplify my code in less steps I would be thankful.

```
import urllib
import time
from datetime import date
today = str(date.today())
import csv

url = "http://localserver" + today + ".log"

urllib.urlretrieve (url, "output.log")
time.sleep(15)
with open("output.log","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
    with open("result.log","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow( (r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[15], r[38], r[39], r[42], r[54], r[90], r[91], r[92], r[111], r[116], r[121], r[122], r[123], r[124]) )
with open('result.log') as myfile:

print (list(myfile)[-1])   #how do I access certain rows here?
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably make use of the advanced module, `requests` as below. The timeout can be increased depending on the time it takes for the download to complete successfully. Furthermore, the two `with open` statements can be consolidated in a single line. What is more, in order to load the line one by one in to the memory, we can make use of `iter_lines` generator. Note that `stream=True` should be set in order to load line one at a time.

```
from datetime import date
import csv
import requests

# Declare variables
today = str(date.today())
url = "http://localserver" + today + ".log"
outfile = 'output.log'

# Instead of waiting for 15 seconds explicitly consider using requests module
# with timeout parameter
response = requests.get(url, timeout=15, stream=True)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Failed to get data:', response.status_code)

with open(outfile, 'w') as dest:
    writer = csv.writer(dest)

    # Walk through the request response line by line w/o loadin gto memory
    line = list(response.iter_lines())[-1]

    # Decode the response to string and split line by line
    reader = csv.reader(line.decode('utf-8').splitlines(), delimiter=';')

    # Read line by line for the splitted content and write to file
    for r in reader:
        writer.writerow((r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[15], r[38], r[39], r[42], r[54], r[90], r[91], r[92],
                             r[111], r[116], r[121], r[122], r[123], r[124]))

print('File written successfully: ' + outfile)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but what if I only need the last line?

Comment: remove the for loop and change `response.iter_lines()` to `list(response.iter_lines())[-1]` and assign to a variable. pass that variable to `csv.reader()` as input. feel free to mark it as best answer if you found it useful.

Comment: OK. I've updated the answer. Please refer to the answer now